# Sum up unstructured cells in excel on the fly [excel]

Tags: excel, text, numbers

Right now I need to sum up some values in certain cells in Excel that are unstructured with text like this:

- Netherlands (325)
- Belgium (214)
- Australia (970)

  etc.

So I am only interested in the total value. Of course I could clean the cells and separate the value from the text and sum it up. But I was wondering if there is a fast solution in excel to ignore the text and just take the value in the cell, since this kind of scenario happens often in daily business.

Best regards!

Answer (score 1):

No, you will must have some a bit more complex formula to accomplish this, as far as I am informed, you cant just take in consideration numbers from text only.

In your case, if **A1 is "Netherlands (325)"**, you would have to filter out number with something like  **=MID(A1, SEARCH("(", A1)+1, (SEARCH(")", A1)) - (SEARCH("(", A1)+1))**, and then sum that column.

Eventually, if you dont want to take another column for numbers, you can do similar thing as upper one, with array formula.

Answer (score 1):

Are your values always 3 numeric characters? Then yes here you go:

```
=SUMPRODCUT(0+RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(A1:A3,")",""),3))
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the formulas so far. What I just experienced is, if you type
in the number of the first cell manually next to it, excel auto fills all cells beneath with the corresponding numbers of the other fields. That is super handy and fast I guess.

Comment: I thought you wouldn't want a helper column?

Comment: With helper column I rather meant to write a "complex" formula to clean it. But this method only takes a few seconds, so this is fine actually